# Display an image from a Byte Array from SQL into an ASPX page that is currently routed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, image

I have the most convoluted and headache of a way to attempt to load am image on a page. I am using VB.Net, my page is routed from a Routes.XML document, I have a SQL database with images stored as varbinary(MAX) fields, I need to load said images from the page into an  control, and everything that i use to use will not work with the routing.

If you need to see code examples let me know, but I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to display an image from bytes in this fashion.

Answer (score 0):

use this  code:

```
Dim Ph As Byte()
Ph = DirectCast(YourImageFromDB), Byte())
               Dim img As Image = Nothing
    Dim stream = New MemoryStream(Ph)

    img = Image.FromStream(stream)
```

Comment: How would i go about setting this image to a control to display the image after that point? im attempting to figure out how to get the image, either from the Response.BinaryWrite() or from another method that i dont understand

Comment: By affecting the variable as :YourControlImage.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);

Comment: There is no ".Image" that my System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image will accept. I actually found out the way to do it from a friend though, so thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having a friend show me how he routed with images. What basically happens is that I needed to create an ASHX file to create the image, and put the full path from the image.ashx that I create as the URL I need. Worked like a charm. First time ever working with a handler file so i had no idea how to use it at first.